# ListView : Setting SimpleCursorAdapter overwrites current ContentView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-2.2-froyo

I very new to the Android SDK but I've managed to create a Dashboard layout and now I'm in the process of building out the activity classes / layouts behind each dashboard button.  I have the click event firing & launching the associated button activity, etc (1 act per button).  I also have a titlebar on each activity layout that allows navigation back to the main dashboard, settings, etc.  Basic look & feel.  All has been working great up until this point.  I'm now attempting to use a ListView on the activity layouts to display data from a local db (sqlite).

In my onCreate() method, I use a SimpleCursorAdapter to attempt to bind a cursor (SQL result) to the ListView in my layout.  I'm actually using 2 layouts here based on a tutorial I did earlier (Notepad).  The 2nd layout is for each "row" present in the cursor.  The problem is that once I set the layout in the SimpleCursorAdapter to this 2nd layout, I lose the titlebar functionality in my first layout.  And obviously if I try to replicate the titlebar code in the 2nd layout, it will be repeated with each instance in the cursor.

Also - all of my "sub" activity classes are inheriting from a base class (FunDashboardActivity) that inherits from Activity.  I cannot use the ListActivity as a base class here because of my design.  Again - I'm completely new to Android and would greatly appreciate any feedback / help.  THANK YOU in advance.

This is my activity code:

```
public class FunSitesActivity extends FunDashboardActivity {

    private int mSiteNumber = 1;
    private FunDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_sites);
        mDbHelper = new FunDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
    }

    private void fillData() {

        // Get Site Data Stored
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllSites();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // Create Cursor Adapter
        String[] from = new String[] { FunDbAdapter.KEY_SITE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.site_row, c, from, to);

        // Create ListView & Set Cursor
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.setAdapter(notes);
        setContentView(lv);  
    }
```

// act_site xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
            android:onClick="onClickHome" />
        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
        <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" />
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_config"
            android:src="@drawable/title_config"
            android:onClick="onClickConfig" />
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
            android:src="@drawable/title_about"
            android:onClick="onClickAbout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/sitelist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_sites"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

// site_row xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  The problem was in my fillData method, where I was setting the contentView to the new ListView instance.  See new code below

```
    private void fillData() {

        // Get Site Data Stored
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllSites();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // Create Cursor Adapter
        String[] from = new String[] { JAMDbAdapter.KEY_SITE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.site_row, c, from, to);

        // Create ListView & Set Cursor 
        // NEW APPROACH
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sitelist);
        lv.setAdapter(notes);

        // OLD APPROACH
        //ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        //lv.setAdapter(notes);
        //setContentView(lv);
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is the "best" approach for what I'm trying to accomplish so any / all feedback would be GREATLY appreciated.